Python script to print only the difference between two text files
I was looking for some help to write a Python script to print only the difference and not anything extra in the output.
For example:
Contents of File1 :-
['Tom','Joe','Kim']

Contents of File2 :-
['Tom','Leo','Cho','Joe','Kim']

I need the following as output when I run the script:
['Leo','Cho']

I tried using difflib library functionalities, but it just doesn't seem to give me only the difference as output!

Is the content of the text file "['Tom','Joe','Kim']" or "Tom'\nJoe\nKim"?
"

Hello @Axeltherabbit it is ['Tom','Joe','Kim'] in my scenario

First you should understand the format of your files, so often we do a little parser (as dumb as possible, e.g. checking []at beginning and end, split with,`, then create a list or a set (set: simpler but no guarantee order will be maintained: users may expect it), .. So. decompose your problem in small steps

Use ast.literal_eval() to parse the file contents into a list. Then difflib should be able to compare the lists.


You can convert your lists to sets, so you can find difference of
unique items.
To keep the same formatting then you convert back set to list.

file1 = ['Tom','Joe','Kim']
file2 = ['Tom','Leo','Cho','Joe','Kim']
diff = list(set(file2)-set(file1)

Output:
['Cho', 'Leo']

Note, if don't know from which list to subtract (i.e the largest one) you can use the following code.
It uses "OR" operator:
diff = list(set(file2)-set(file1)|set(file1)-set(file2))


You can use the set.union(..) and set.intersection(..) methods to obtain what you are looking for.
It is included in standard, no import to make:
file1 = ['Tom','Joe','Kim']
file2 = ['Tom','Leo','Cho','Joe','Kim']

result = set(file1).union(set(file2)) - set(file1).intersection(set(file2))

print( list(redsult) )

Output is:
['Leo', 'Cho']

